# Runtime.getRuntime().exec redirect issue

Tags: java, linux, file-io

we used the following codes to merge 2 files with same header and columns:

```
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "tail -n +2 " + file1 + " >> " + file2});
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {}
```

However, we have weird issue that one file content is missing after merging and it doesn't have any exception or failures from the logs, we have hundreds of such merges everyday and the code never have issues before. File size is between 1-2G(we have much bigger files without merge issues) and we don't have space issues when it runs either.

Does anyone have any clue on how this could happen?

Comment: **1)** Which file content is missing `file1` or `file2`? **2)** Is this error reproducible? **3)** What do you do with the lines inside the `while-loop`? Maybe you could get rid of the shell processing? **4)** What is the return value of `waitFor()` in such case? **5)** What have you done already to find the origin of the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is my comment: 1) just tab delimited txt file 2) not reproduciable, worked fine before and for other feeds running at similar time 3) nothing in the while loop. 4) it doesn't check return value for waitFor() 5) we rerun the process and new file looks fine, and I can see 2 files were created and merged without any issue during rerun

Comment: I will add error handling for waitFor() for now, let the code throw exception when returned value is not 0.